# Find all rows *without* a flag (SET data type)

Tags: mysql, logic, bit-manipulation

I was trying to find all all "classes" without the "interface" modifier, so I wrote:

```
SELECT * FROM classes WHERE modifiers & ~0x80
```

Where `0x80` is obviously the interface modifier. This did indeed filter out the "interfaces", but it also excluded classes with no flags. So I had to modify it to:

```
SELECT * FROM classes WHERE modifiers=0 OR modifiers & ~0x80
```

Is that the normal way of doing this? Seems funny that I have to do 2 checks. My bitwise logic might be a bit rusty.

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting stuff where any of the bits, except bit 8, is 1. Just test for the bit being 0 explicitly: `where (modifiers & 0x80) = 0`

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to mask (&) off the value you're expecting so then it doesn't matter what the other values are (including if they are zero).  I'm assuming (you don't specify) that the `interface modifier` is the eighth bit.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM classes WHERE modifiers &0x80=0x00;
```

So here we're saying if the 8th bit isn't set then we're good... doesn't matter what any other bits are (0 or 1)  Example test cases:

```
SELECT 0x00 &0x80=0 FROM dual; //True
SELECT 0x7F &0x80=0 FROM dual; //True
SELECT 0x80 &0x80=0 FROM dual; //False
SELECT 0x8F &0x80=0 FROM dual; //False
```

(0x00 can of course be shortened to 0.. just for readability ;))